# How can I make JWT more secure?

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt, basic-authentication

I am creating JWT based authentication in my application deployed on Wildfly server.

1. For any request arriving at my server, the request is validated to be having a Basic Auth header. In cases, where I don't get the header, I get the POST request payload with Username and Password. I wrap the request with  HttpServletRequestWrapper and add Basic auth header to it and call another application which returns 200 OK after authenticating with Login module automatically. Also, I have a singleton with a ConcurrentHashMap<String, MyUser> in which I store user logging in and the User object with other user details.
2. On receiving 200 OK, I create a JWT and return it to the client. The client then sends JWT with each request to the EJB services. I get the Authorization header as Bearer *******. I decode the user from the JWT token, then using the map, I again create Basic Auth header and send request to another application which exposes the services only when the Basic Auth header is found.

**My doubts:**

a) In 1) above, I am sending POST payload, which I can see in Browser network logs. And, I can plainly see the username and password being sent. Is there something extra that needs to be done to prevent this. Or, this wont be visible to other users? Or, https is the solution?

b) In 2) above, anybody can get my token if they are doing MITM attack or know my credentials as in a).
Then, they can seamlessly get access the services. **Can, I add IP address of the requested user and store in the map and while validating JWT, validate the IP as well so I can prevent MITM attacks?**

There are other posts on SFO and Okta Developer I visited, and they answered about why and how JWT is insecure. But, I am curious, if I can do anything extra in my case which I am missing?

Comment: SSL should already protect you well from MITM attacks.  As for the JWT, if you _don't_ want anyone to see its contents, then encrypt it on the server.  If you don't mind people seeing it, then don't encrypt.  In either case, the JWT should be tamper-proof.

Comment: So, is the SSL the solution for both of my doubts?

Comment: If you encrypt the JWT, then theoretically even without SSL no one can read it.  With SSL, an encrypted JWT should be virtually non readable.  And even if they change something, it would fail the checksum check on the server anyway.

Comment: Ok, so I have signed it with a secret key already. I am also unauthorizing changed JWT tokens, but, what if someone gets hold of the correct token, SSL should come into picture there, right?

Comment: Please review how JWT work.  They are tamper proof.

Comment: I agree and have verified it to be tamper-proof, but I read this link at Okta Developer:

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/06/20/what-happens-if-your-jwt-is-stolen

It says that yes JWT being stolen can be a problem. That, anyone can use that JWT (not tampering it), to access the services. What should I do then? Will SSL help?

Comment: SSL only provides encryption across the network.  Once it reaches your browser, the JWT will be decrypted.  In that case, you would need to additionally encrypt the JWT on the server before you send it over SSL.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I am still in some doubts but some are resolved. I will take it up in my team now. Cheers!

Comment: TLS will protect you from MITM attacks, and prevent your token from getting stolen in transit. But usually tokens are stolen using XSS. Tokens should never be stored in local storage, instead they should be sent as secured cookies, out of the browsers reach. Thats why other security measures should be implemented as CORS, CSRF, Content Security Policies (CSP). Its the combination of all these implemented security features that prevent all types of attacks that can lead to stolen tokens. And also ofc, always use short lived tokens.

Answer (score 1):

There are several levers you can pull here to vary the amount of security in your JWT setup.  Consider the following options:

1. **No SSL and no encryption of your JWT.**  In this case, your JWT would be visible not only to the user, but also to any man in the middle who is listening (either legitimately or maliciously).  This means that any sensitive information contained within the JWT might be visible to others.  However, the JWT still cannot be hacked, even in this maximally unsecure setup.  The reason for this is that every JWT contains a checksum, which is a hash of the token's content, signed using a key which only the *server* has.  So even if a MITM or user messes around with your JWT, the server would immediately recognize that the token has been hacked when the checksum fails.
2. **SSL is enabled, but the JWT is not encrypted.**  This offers the same protection as above plus it also makes it very unlikely that a MITM could ever get a hold of any JWT going to or fro in transit.  Therefore, sensitive information inside the JWT would only be visible to the recipient.
3. **SSL is enabled, and the token is encrypted.**  In this maximally secure setup, no MITM can see the JWT in transit.  Also, once received, the user must decrypt the JWT using some key.  Therefore, even if the JWT ends up in a cookie, in theory it is not a security risk, provided that it can't be decrypted by anyone other than the intended recipient.

Most of the time, we will tend to lean towards option #2, but we will not put sensitive information into the JWT.  There is no need for storing a login password in a JWT, as the token itself can prove authentication.  The JWT is tamper proof, and if someone malicious finds a way to see claims such as the expiry date or username, we generally don't care.

Comment: Thanks for your comments yesterday. I revisited the possibility of SSL in addition to @Toerktumlare comment of having CSRF,CORS and CSP policies as well. However, since it is a servlet application and not spring, it will take some effort to implement.

Comment: Where would the user get the key to decrypt the JWT from?

Answer (score 1):

1 -> Yes HTTPS is the only solution no matter how much secure you make your APIs without
HTTPS MITM attacks are easy.

2-> With multiple benefits come some tradeoffs, JWT leak or stealing is a real problem, and it is not easy to solve, adding an IP address to JWT is not a good idea as they get to change a lot and you user have to authenticate again.
What you try is a quick JWT expiration in this case user has to authenticate every time the token is expired, now for solving this problem you can use a ***refresh token***, it is not so hard to implement.

wanna get deeper here you go --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPrhem174Ws&t=1089s

Comment: Yes, Agree. Valid point to mention the variability of IP address. And, I missed that. Silly.